# werkzeug.routing.BuildError with Flask -- trying to build a very simple webapp

Tags: python, html, flask

I'm trying to develop a simple webapp that prompts the user for their address, requests forecast information from the NWS through their API, and prints out the results, but I'm running into some issues tying together the HTML and the Python script. I'm still new to programming in general and this is all a very rough copy at the moment, here's the relevant code:

weather.py:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def home():
    return render_template('weather.html')

@app.route('/forecast', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def forecast():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        location = request.form['address']

        # gets the weather information

        return render_template('forecast.html', varying_forecast = forecast, wfo = wfo_info)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

weather.html:

```
  <form action="{{ url_for('forecast') }}" method="post">
    Enter your address here: <input type="text" name="address"><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Get My Forecast!"><br>
  </form>
```

When I try to go to 127.0.0.1:5000 I receive this error: "werkzeug.routing.BuildError: Could not build url for endpoint 'forecast'. Did you mean 'home' instead?" To the best of my knowledge this error occurs when url_for fails to find a route, but given that the forecast function does exist I'm confused where the error is coming from. Even after commenting out the form tag in the HTML the error persists. I tried getting rid of the "wfo" and "varying_forecast" in the return statement but that also didn't do anything. The only way to fix it is by setting the url_for of the action of the form to home, but I don't see any way to run the code in there and return the forecast information, considering it's already returning the home page. I'm having trouble understanding why it fails to display the weather.html page as written.

Comment: I can't actually reproduce this error, code works fine for me. Can you show project's file structure?

Comment: Anyway, you shoud definitely add `from flask import request` for your /forecast to work

Comment: @biryulin04 Added that in and changed the file structure - apparently the Python script was saving to a different place than where I thought. Thank you!